# Can you start Jenkins jobs while using Google Login with API Tokens?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, token, single-sign-on, google-account

I'm using the Google Login plugin with Jenkins (i.e.: Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Security Realm -> Login with Google). I'm trying to switch my git hook to start jobs using API tokens instead of crumbs, [as described here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/).

However when running curl or wget as instructed:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge \                                                                         
    --user="MY GOOGLE EMAIL" --password="MY API TOKEN I GENERATED AT /CONFIGURE" \
     https://myProject.jenkins.com/job/myJob/build
```

the request is redirected to Google's external identity provider. Is there a way to make this work? Do these two features not coexist?